# Excel Formula Vlookup the value by referring Row and Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the sheet1 i have a table called working days of the countries as shown in the below image.

[image]

In the Sheet2 i have 10 columns in that based on the country and month by referring the this table i am trying to populate the values, When i tried doing by Vlookup the first row alone getting populated, but in the second row the header from `F1:T1` is getting changed to `F2:T2` so rest of the cells showing as `#NA`.

[image]

Anyone can you please give a solution for my issue. Here is the formula i have used.

```
=VLOOKUP(I1,Sheet1!F2:T7,MATCH(Sheet2!M1,Sheet1!F1:T1,0))
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: But still when you drag this formula it is getting changed to =VLOOKUP(I2,Sheet1!$F$2:$T$7,MATCH(M2,Sheet1!$F2:$T2,0)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the symbol `$` to lock the ranges, and the false condition to match exact values in the `VLOOKUP`.

It should be like:

`=VLOOKUP(I1,Sheet1!$F$2:$T$7,MATCH(M1,Sheet1!$F$1:$T$1,0),0)`

Or instead of `VLOOKUP` use `HLOOKUP` like:

`=HLOOKUP(M1,Sheet1!$F$1:$T$7,MATCH(I1,Sheet1!$F$2:$F$7,0),0)`

Comment: Hello virtualdvid, Your VLOOKUP formula works perfectly. Thank you so much for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

In general, combining the `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions is a superior option to `VLOOKUP`. For example, `=INDEX(Sheet1!F:F,MATCH(Sheet2!M1,Sheet1!F1:T1,0))`. This allows you to go left-to-right or right-to-left as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Snip for Index Match functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbx4s.jpg) Using Vlookup won't work here because in the 2nd table you are repeating the country, unlike the first table. Use a combination of index match function, this is little trickier than the vlookup but it will fulfill your requirements.

Since I don't have the exact table you shared so I created a table on my end and sharing the snip here.